# Radius of convergence for Taylor series?!

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

Given is:

$f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x} $

I need the Taylor series in $a = 0$, so:

$$T(x,0) = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty ((-1)^n* \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} ) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n * \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

since for

$g(x) = \sin x \Rightarrow g(0) = 0 \\
g'(x)= \cos x \Rightarrow g'(0) = 1 \\
g''(x) = -\sin x \Rightarrow g''(0) = 0$
..
I get: $T(x) = f(0) + f'(0)*x + \dots \Rightarrow \sin x \sim x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} = $(the series I used above)

I hope the series above is correct.

Now I need the convergence radius. I tried using Leibnitz (alternating series test), but $\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} $ is not monotonuous falling..

Can you please help me? :)

Comment: Write down the power series of $\sin(x)$ and then devied it by $x$.

Comment: Didn't I just do this?

Comment: You can show that the remainder term divided by $x$ converges to zero as $n$ approaches $\infty$ and for every real $x$. And then use ratio test and prove that the series is absolutely convergent with radius of convergence $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct series written.

To find convergence, you can use the ratio test, just as one often uses to show that $\sin x$ has infinite radius of convergence. The work is very similar and very straightforward to the proof of the radius of convergence for the Taylor series of $\sin x$.